# is it possible to search for C++ statement by types and operands?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, vtk, decltype, automated-refactoring

Is there a method or tool for searching in C++ based on types in an expression? For example, let's say we have:

```
    m_polydata = Normals->GetOutput(); //NOTE: POSSIBLE LEAK!!
    // decltype(m_polydata)           is  vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> 
    // decltype(Normals->GetOutput()) is  vtkPolyData*
```

and we know it's often undesirable to assign vtkPolyData* to vtkSmartPointer.

I'd like to search in a bunch of files for expressions of the form:

```
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData>  =  vtkPolyData*
```

or more generally:

```
    LHS<Type1> = RHS<Type2>
```

Can this kind of search be done in a somewhat easy manner? Maybe there's some Eclipse plugin or GDB wrapper or Visual Studio plugin?

Comment: `grep` can do that, I'm sure. I'm not proficient enough in grepping in order to give you a ready to use expression, but it can't be that hard :-)

Comment: there is surprisingly few type-based refactoring tools, I just know that many write their own transformers based on LLVM Clang. You can look at the slides from this talk to get a feel for how it works: http://2012.cppnow.org/session/refactoring-c-with-clang/

Comment: @JorenHeit:  How would grep manage to match the types?

Comment: I thought he just wanted to locate them. And because grep looks for regex's, it would certainly be able to find lines of the form he's describing.

Comment: @JorenHeight   No Grep wouldn't work-  where do you see the type specified in text here? "m_polydata = Normals->GetOutput();"  you need a compiler-like thing to extract types.